# Firemonkey Form always restores to wsNormal

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

I don't know if this could be a BUG or just some configuration.

By setting the form to `WndowState = wsMaximized` and pressing Windows+D (Show Desktop), when the form is restored from the taskbar the WindowState changes to `WndowState = wsNormal`.

This only happens in Firemonkey, in VCL it doesn't.

Would there be any solution to keep the form always in wsMaximized?

Answer (score 0):

I think this ought to be reported as a bug.

But I think I have a workaround to this.  When the form is hidden the `OnDeactivate` event is fired.  Of course that is also fired if another form takes the focus.  But if `SetBounds()` is then called without `OnActivate` being fired first, as far as I've been able to tell, this only happens when the form is being shown again from the Show Desktop state.

So this code seems, from the testing I've done, to resolve the issue:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDeactivate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    WasMaximised:   Boolean;
  public
    procedure   SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer); override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WasMaximised:=False;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDeactivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WasMaximised:=WindowState=TWindowState.wsMaximized;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  if WasMaximised then begin
    WasMaximised:=False;
    WindowState:=TWindowState.wsNormal;
    WindowState:=TWindowState.wsMaximized;
  end;
end;
```